# What 80s sci-fi novel has a volunteer take an injection that increases IQ?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to remember the name of a sci-fi novel I read in the nineties, when I was kid. It was a library book which, from what I can remember, was written maybe in the early 80's.

I remember in the first chapter a volunteer is injected with a drug that increases his IQ. As I recall, there is a random chance the drug might cause severe retardation instead.

After the drug takes effect, he walks out, and sees details he couldn't fathom before, like in the lobby the marble (columns I think?) has more meaning.

---

As pointed out in the comments below, it's **not** *Flowers for Algernon*.

Comment: I remember reading a novel that had this same idea. In the novel I read, the main character had a brother who had taken the injection and gotten an adverse reaction. The drug also caused most people whose IQ increased to suffer from minor aches and pains.

Comment: yeah...I remember something about a brother too

Comment: Was there a mirrored test with a rodent like a rat that also had an increase in IQ, then later died?

Comment: Flowers for Algernon by Daniel Keyes? There isn't a brother, but his sister is mentioned quite a bit, and there is a mouse.

Comment: @Zoe That sounds like what I remember..

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is definitely NOT Flowers for Algernon. In FfA, it was a procedure (not a drug). Also, the main character had been mentally challenged when the story began and reverted as the story progressed. I'm reasonably sure I read the novel @sleo is talking about (though I can't remember author or title) and the two stories are quite distinctive.

Comment: Thanks Zoe, FfA is an amazing book but unfortunately @Donald.McLean is right, that's not the novel I was thinking of.

Comment: When did you read it? It doesn't have to be the exact year, just a decade or part of a decade (1940s, early 1990s, etc.).

Comment: @sjl I read this back in the 90's, but it was a library book which, from what I can remember, was written maybe in the early 80's

Comment: I was wondering about Asimov's Pebble in the Sky which also has a man's intelligence increased, but it doesn't seem to match your description.

Comment: The title made me think of "Brain Wave" by Poul Anderson. The plot is clearly inconsistent with what you're asking about, but it's a great book.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like [*The R-Master*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/087997155X) by Gordon R. Dickson.

From [goodreads.com](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1133491.The_R_Master):

> A repressively benevolent bureaucracy, intent on limiting and harnessing the effects of an IQ-boosting drug known as R-47, is thwarted by an underground led by an R-Master, latest of the drug-produced supergeniuses. Our hero's apolitical to start with but his chemically expanded perspective reveals the flaws in his superficial utopia. Energetically suspenseful, though the intriguing premise of an intelligence-enhancing drug might have been more fully developed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's it. Except that I probably read the edition released under the title The Last Master (1984). The original edition was from 1973.

Answer (score 7):

Could be Ted Chiang's *Understand*:

http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/under.htm

Comment: Thanks for recommending this story..I have read it and found it really amazing, actually reading this particular story, is what triggered the memory of a book I had read as a child and just couldn't remember the darn name of it!

Comment: This is not from the 80's

Answer (score 4):

Just thought I'd mention "The Dark Fields" by Alan Glynn, basis of the movie "Limitless", though it wasn't written until 2001, so I doubt it's at least the novel *everyone* is thinking of.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but the 'MDT-48' is a pill- just as in the movie.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this is the book I was looking for.

Answer (score -3):

flowers for algernon maybe, has a similar plot to the one you described

Comment: The OP has already stated in the comments that it is *not* Flowers For Algernon.