# Sci-Fi Story Involving Illegal Drug that Temporarily Turns User into Super-Genius

Tags: story-identification

Story was written before 1980s - perhaps from the 50s or 60s involving a character who takes an illegal drug that temporarily turns him into a super genius.

I believe that part of the story involved an ancient alien maze which the character uses the drug to navigate.  I'm a little sketchy on this part.

The story is not Rogue Moon.

Comment: Might be [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27044/what-80s-sci-fi-novel-has-a-volunteer-take-an-injection-that-increases-iq/31876#31876)

Comment: I have The R-Master (my version is actually titled [*The Last Master*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Last-Master-Gordon-Dickson/dp/0812535626)). I can't find any mention of an alien maze, and the effect of the drug RIV is permanent not temporary.

Answer (score 2):

One of Keith Laumer's Retief books (I'm pretty sure it was "Retief and the Warlords", published 1978) has a character use an alien drug that ended up temporarily making him super fast (like fast enough everything else stands still).

I think the drug was originally supposed to give him a slight edge, maybe think or react a bit quicker - but obviously had an exaggerated reaction cross-species.  I believe he uses it to compete in an arena, and later race over terrain to mess with an army (not specifically recalling a maze, but it could be).

I realize super smart is not the same thing as super fast, but the character is also portrayed as pretty much a genius, out thinking and out plotting others in the series, and he does use the drug to navigate scenarios where he could not have done otherwise - and the scenario sounded similar enough to me I thought it was worth offering as an outside possibility.  I hope you find it.

Comment: Don't think you're right, but I loved that particular Retief story. The part where he lifts a car by virtue of *f=ma* was a blast.